# Is there a way to get items back if they're lost when you download a mod and don't save beforehand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ok, I've downloaded a bunch of mods for him, but this was the first time the mod came with an installer.  The installer asked if I saved all mods and I did not and told it to install anyway.  Not good.

Honestly, I do not know much about Minecraft.  The mods are still in the mod folder, but they don't appear to be working.  All his cool Items are gone.

He explained it to me that the mod did not create the items, but he had to go into a world and find/build items.  I think he put a lot of time into finding and building these things and I just wiped it all out.  Feel like a terrible Dad.

Can anyone help this dummy get his items back?

Comment: Step 1 would be to get the old mods working again, which is something we can't help you with with the information you provided. Ideally, a new, clean installation of Minecraft Forge should do the trick, since the mods are still in the folder. Try that. However, if you opened and closed his world without the mods, the items and blocks from these mods will have been automatically removed by the game as they were invalid. Your best bet would then be to cheat them back in, which might be hard depending on which item it was.

Comment: You could use another mod like "TooManyItems" or "NotEnoughItems" to get them back into the game... but this requires you/him to know exactly, which items he had before. But when saving the world, the nod-items are seen as invalid and get deleted. (see MrLemon's comment)

Comment: There are certain miss that do create world backups. Without knowing what mods you had not much more I can help you with. Note that world data does not store what a player had in their inventory or ender chests as